# How to ensure that a randomly-generated velocity vector moves the camera forward within a valid arc?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, camera, game-physics

I spawn a camera in a scene using random coordinates for `x` and `y` and setting `z=0` and orient the camera so that it looks on the point (0, 0, 0). My goal is to move the camera forward using randomly-generated velocity vectors on the ground (so `z` stays `0`). I want to ensure that the new position of the camera is within a valid range after moving it forward, defined in degrees with respect to the current focus point/direction. More specifically, the way I determine "valid range" is by ensuring that the new position is within 45 degrees of the old camera's focus point (-45 degrees to the left and +45 degrees to the right). Can someone write a pseudocode on how I can achieve this?

Here's my attempt to do this but this doesn't seem to be the correct way to help me achieve what I want:

```
camera_dir = (0, 0, 0) - current_cam_pos
while True:
    vel_vec=[uniform(-max_vel, max_vel), uniform(-max_vel, max_vel)] # generate a random velocity vector
    new_pos = camera_dir + vel_vec # compute a new position (and camera direction vector) for the camera
    if (compute_angle(new_pos, camera_dir) < 45 or compute_angle(new_pos, camera_dir) > 315):
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```java
// 45° in rad
double validAngle = Math.PI / 4;

ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

Vector2D camPosition = new Vector2D(0, -1);
Vector2D camTarget= new Vector2D(0, 0);
Vector2D camDirection = camTarget.subtract(camPosition).normalize();

double cosPhi = camDirection.x;
double phi = Math.acos(cosPhi);
double alpha = random.nextDouble(-validAngle, validAngle);
double angle = phi + alpha;

Vector2D velocity = new Vector2D(Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle)).multiply(speed);
Vector2D newPosition = position.add(velocity.multiply(deltaTime));
```

This approach is written in Java but should be very portable to other languages.

However, I don't think this is a perfect solution because this approach uses a lot of trigonometric functions, which might be costly in a game in which you have to update the camera in every frame.

The method uses the angle between the cam direction and the x-Axis as well as the maximum angle allowed to calculate the final vector. First I calculate the cosine of the angle between the cam direction and the x-Axis and name it `phi`. The cosine of phi is: `camDirection.dotProduct(new Vector2D(1, 0));`, which is the x component of the cam direction. So let's say your cam direction is (0, 1), which is the y-axis. Then `phi` is 90°. Now you just generate a random number between -45° and 45° (convert it in rad) and add this angle `alpha` to `phi`. The resulting `angle` will be in the range [135°;45°] relative to the x-axis. Now you have an angle relative to the x-Axis and compute your 2D vector with `(cos(angle), sin(angle))`. You can test if the generated direction vector is in that maximum allowed angle with:

```java
Vector2D newDirection = new Vector2D(Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle));

double cosBeta = newDirection.dotProduct(camDirection);
double beta = Math.acos(cosBeta);
```

`beta` will always be in the desired range and represents the angle between the camera direction and the generated velocity direction. The following picture should illustrate this method:
[image]

And thank you for pointing out that `camDirection.dotProduct(new Vector2D(1, 0));` represents the x-component of the camera direction. I changed that. :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure actually about your approach now. Could you please help me understand why are you only using the `x` compoennt of `camDirection`? Also, what does angle capture? How does generating the final velocity vector using `angle` ensure that the velocity vector is within `PI/2` radians on both sides of the direction vector? When I print `angle` I sometimes see numbers like 200 degrees or more, which seems to be wrong unless there a mathematical reasoning behind it which I am not aware of

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: And please note that PI/2 are 90° and therefore the allowed range would be [180°;0°] for `angle` when the camera direction is aligned with the y-axis.